# Cambiar formato a columan con openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

agradezo cualquier ayuda ya que estoy tratanbdo de cambiar el formato de la columna SALDO_CAPITAL (K) de un archivo de excel, pero no logro hacer que cambie a formato a número, me arroja el siguiente error.

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'number_format'

Este es mi codigo:

```
    print (log_reg+" depuracion de archivo")
    qd = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:/Q_DIARIO/Query Diario"+query_dia+".xlsx")
    h = qd.active
    print (log_reg+" archivo abierto")
    r=0
    for SALDO_CAPITAL in h:
        SALDO_CAPITAL.number_format = '0'
        h.append(g)
        r+=1
        print(r)
```

Comment: g ya es una celda. No puedes obtener una celda de una celda.

Comment: SALDO_CAPITAL es una tupla de celdas. Representa una fila del xlsx. Y como dice el error, una tupla no tiene el atributo number_format. Tendrás que iterar también sobre esa tupla y obtener las celdas. Y luego a cada celda darle el formato. Por cierto, g no existe en tu código. Ejecutarlo incluso teniendo los archivos y solucionando el problema que tienes daría un NameError.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma seria cargar el archivo de Excel a una variable, luego aplicar las acciones de hojas de cálculo sobre la variable y finalmente guardar la variable en el mismo archivo para que hagan efecto los cambios, aqui siguiendo la interpretación de tu codigo:

```
# Abrir las bibliotecas necesarias
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Font, Border, Side
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
.
.
.
# Abrir el archivo
workbook = load_workbook("D:/Q_DIARIO/Query Diario"+query_dia+".xlsx")

# Seleccionar la hoja de cálculo
sheet = workbook['Nombre-de-la-hoja']

# Aplicar formato de fecha a la columna "SALDO_CAPITAL"
for cell in sheet['SALDO_CAPITAL']:
     cell.number_format = '0'
.
.
.
# Guardar los cambios
workbook.save("D:/Q_DIARIO/Query Diario"+query_dia+".xlsx")
```